# C - For loop based on variable doesn't iterate correct number of times

Tags: c

nCities becomes 8 at runtime in my current test case. I make sure of this by having it printed via printf. However, the loop seems to only iterate once when I use i <= nCities. If I use i <= 8, it works fine. Why is this?

```
  int nCities = 0;
  scanf("%d", &nCities);

  if (!nCities == 0)
  {
    printf("Number of cities: %d \n", nCities);

    char tempCity[3];

    for(int i=1; i <= nCities; i++)
    {

      printf("Number of cities: %d \n", nCities);
      scanf( "%s", tempCity );
      printf( "%s", tempCity );

    }
```

Comment: Probably `tempCity[3];` is too small.

Comment: There's not enough information. What are you typing, in order to cause the loop to iterate only once? I compiled this myself, and it works just fine (in that respect, there's other issues).

Comment: On Intel, if you read more than two characters, then `nCities` will be overwritten.

Comment: @user3121023 Why 2?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Can you please explain: How does reading information after I've already read and stored nCities affect nCities?

Comment: If the city is length 3 the array must be length 4 for the `NUL` terminator which every C string needs.

Comment: Could you post your entire code then? I can't see any issues (besides the one already mentioned about `tempCity` not being large enough) with what you've posted. It seems to work just fine.

Comment: A string of 3 lettes requires 4 bytes of memory for the terminating null character.

Comment: Ah, the problem was not having space for the null character. Thank you guys for pointing that out to me!

Comment: The stack grows down. `tempCity` is allocated on the stack, below `nCities`. So the fourth byte (the null character) overwrites 1 byte of the integer `nCities`.

Comment: Now go and change `tempCity` to at least 4 bytes and see what happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the input “ABC ”, the code `scanf( "%s", tempCity );` puts the three characters “ABC” in `tempCity` and terminates them with a null character. However, `tempCity` is defined to have only three characters, with `char tempCity[3];`. Since the bounds of the array are exceeded by the `scanf`, the resulting behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Fix this by making `tempCity` large enough to contain all the data required of it and/or limiting the `scanf` by specifying a maximum field width, such as `%3f`. (Note that with `%3f`, `tempCity` should be defined as `char tempCity[4]`, to allow for three characters plus the null character.)